# How to let registered users save data?

Tags: php, mysql

I already have set up a database for a login system. Visitors can now register and login. I'm using phpMyAdmin and php files. This works.

But now I want users who are logged in to save data. For the sake of testing, let's say I want them to save their favorite color. I'm assuming I need some kind of form for them to input data. See simple example below.

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
<label>My favorite color:</label>
<input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

How can I make sure that the color they save will be saved under their username in the database? It's difficult for me to find the answer to this question.

In phpMyAdmin I have a table called 'users' with columns: id, username, password and created_at.

Not sure what more information I need to add. Let me know if you guys need more info. Thank you!

EDIT:

Thank you for your input guys.

@brombeer and @user3425506
Yes, the column 'id' in table 'users' is a primary key.
I've added a table called 'colors'. This table has columns 'id' and 'favorite_color'. The column 'favorite_color' is standard, haven't done anything special to this one. However, in case of 'id', I have kept it identical to the 'id' in table 'users', which is `INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`. But I'm wondering if this is necessary and I also wonder how the two tables are now connected.

I've added `name="favorite-color"` in the html form.

On the page where logged in users start there's the following code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
```

On the page where users login I've found 'loggedin' under the following code:

```
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
```

Does this mean I need `$_SESSION['loggedin']` under the html form?

Comment: How do you keep track of a logged in user?

Comment: use session to maintain the user id after login.

Comment: @brombeer Not sure what you mean. When a user is registered, I will have their username etc. stored in the database under table 'users'.

Comment: @Rabby Isn't session only used to store data temporarily?

Comment: When they _login_, not when they _register_. You'd need to store some sort of info about a logged in user, probably in a session. You should already have the info you need in a session

Comment: @brombeer I checked and indeed, the page where a logged in user starts, starts with <?php session_start(); But I kind of get the feeling that my explanation is not clear enough. What I would like is for the user to enter personal data on my site and save it. And for example, next time they log in, they can still see their saved data. I just don't know where to start when it comes to the existing table 'users' in phpMyAdmin and when it comes to php code on the page where users can enter data. Hope this makes it more clear. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You could create a table called favorite_color with columns called id, user_id and color.

Comment: This really needs more info about your database structure. You should have a primary key in your users table by which each user can uniquely be identified. Either create a new column in the `users` table to store that colour or (preferred way) create a new table to store additional user data and "link" it to the `users` table via f.e. the `user_id`.

Comment: @brombeer Thank you for your input! To keep things more orderly I've edited my question and have referred to your feedback and someone else's. Again, thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Don't get this the wrong way, I won't lead you through the whole process, that's not what this site is for. Find a decent up to date tutorial that teaches how to relate f.e. articles, blogposts or something else to a user, maybe read one or two tutorials on mysql. Basically, when you save the data, make sure `$_SESSION["id"]` (which I assume is the logged in user's id) is saved with the data as the user's id. If you have _any_ problems with your code you're more than welcome to come back and ask.

Comment: @brombeer Yes, I have already tried tutorials before I asked the question here. The problem thus far with these tutorials is that they are not complete. Like I now know that I need to send data to a database in a session. What you often see is that they only talk about how to send data to a DB with form action to a .php file that connects to a DB and then inserts the data into it. That's fairly easy. But to send data during and connect it to a user's session seems to be a different story. Anyway, thank you for the trouble. I will investigate further!

Answer (score 0):

Add a name attribute to your input element such as favorite-color like this:

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
<label>My favorite color:
    <input type="text" name="favorite-color">
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Now when the user submits the form the value they entered will be available in the variable, $_POST['favorite-color'].

If the user is logged in, their user id (from your users table) should be available as a session variable such as $_SESSION['user'] (you need to check your code to see the exact name to use).

If you create a table in your database called colors with a field called user_id and a field called favorite_color then you should be able to insert a row into that table using the $_POST and $_SESSION variables described.

Then whenever someone logs in, you can retrieve their favorite color by selecting the row from the colors table which has a user_id value the same as the $_SESSION['user'] value of the logged in user.

This is an overview of the whole process. There is quite a lot of detail involved to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your input! To keep things more orderly I've edited my question and have referred to your feedback and someone else's. Again, thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: in your colors table you can have an id column but you also want a user_id field as well. The id column is just an id for each row which you may or may not have a use for. The user_id field is a foreign key. It relates to a row in a different table (ie foreign). It is that which will enable you to link that user to their favorite color.

Comment: Have now done what you said. I also found the code to assign a foreign key and everything. I will investigate further. Thank you for the trouble!